# Not a JSON Object from google

Tags: java, json, gson

I'm trying to make a translate program using the google API.
This is how far i've got.

```
package me.kyllian.translate;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
    System.setProperty("http.agent", "Chrome");
    String link = "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=%from%&tl=%to%&dt=t&q=%text%";
    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("What to translate? :");
    String input = reader.next();
    reader.close();
    URL url = new URL(link.replace("%from%", "en").replace("%to%", "nl").replace("%text%", input));
    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

    connection.connect();
    JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
    JsonElement jsonElement = jsonParser.parse(new InputStreamReader((InputStream) connection.getContent()));
    JsonObject obj = jsonElement.getAsJsonObject();

    String routeID = null;
    if (connection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) routeID = obj.get("Route").getAsString();
}
```

My JSON string is:

[[["Goedemorgen","goodmorning",null,null,1]],null,"en"]

But it doesn't seem to be a JSON object, is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Getting `.txt` file from this request. Please refer their documentation https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_a/single?client=gtx&sl=%from%&tl=%to%&dt=t&q=%text%

Comment: The link you sent doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry. Please refer https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/ and see the samples given by them. based on your technology stack choose from their samples.